# Why is my web-app using more and more ram with each server request?

Tags: angular, typescript

So every second i call this function to get the latest data because my app is a real time app:

```
getInformation() {
    this.dateService.getDates().subscribe((data: Appointment[]) => {
      this.totalDates = data;
    });
    this.presentationService.getPresentations().subscribe((data: Presentation[]) => {
      this.totalPresentations = data;
    });
    this.roomService.getBookings().subscribe((data: Booking[]) => {
      this.totalBookings = data;
    })
  }
```

If i now look at the task in the taskmanager, every second it uses 0-1 mb more ram. On my windows pc this is no problem at all but i want to display this web-app on a rasperry-pi kiosk system. The raspberry-pi im using only has 926 mb's of ram so it runs out of ram after roughly 20 minutes or so which means it freezes.

I've tried calling this function less often (for example every 3 seconds) but this just resulted in the ram size growing smaller.

Answer (score 1):

> every second i call this function

That is an issue. I assume each call triggers an HTTP request (presumably to the same domain). Browsers usually have a hard limit for maximum number of simultaneous connections to a domain (Chrome - 6). One quick workaround would be to use RxJS `forkJoin` and `unsubscribe` from the previous requests to cancel any impending requests before triggering another. Try the following

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  infoSubscription: any;

  getInformation() {
    if (this.infoSubscription) {
      this.infoSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    this.infoSubscription = forkJoin({
        dates: this.dateService.getDates(),
        presentations: this.presentationService.getPresentations(),
        bookings: this.roomService.getBookings()
      }
    )
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        this.totalDates = response.dates;
        this.totalPresentations = response.presentations;
        this.totalBookings = response.bookings;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.infoSubscription) {
      this.infoSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

This method is still dirty since we are manually triggering a request every second. It might happen that the backend takes more than a second to respond, and we lose the information. Better way in this scenario would be to use Server-Sent Events.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of doing subscribe on every call!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you use `setInterval`. This will call a pile up of stack frames on the heap. The multiple subscribes you do, should not affect the memory, because there is no memory leak, as long as the `Observable` completes. You can however rewrite your call in a more `rxjs` way:

This means you only have to call `getInformation()` once (so don't call this more than once):

```
getInformation() {
  interval(1000, animationFrameScheduler).pipe(
    switchMap(() => forkJoin({
      dates: this.dateService.getDates(),
      presentations: this.presentationService.getPresentations(),
      bookings: this.roomService.getBookings()
    }))
  ).subscribe(({ dates, presentations, bookings }) => {
    this.totalDates = dates;
    this.totalPresentations = presentations;
    this.totalBookings = bookings;
  });
}
```

You can play around with the `scheduler`. Maybe the `animationFrameScheduler` will not cause as many stack frames as the normal `asyncScheduler`.